# What do you call the act of "misusing" metaphors?

Tags: creative-writing, metaphor, figures-of-speech

What do you call the act of "misusing" metaphors or using it in a way that's not accepted or considered wrong by most authors. I am trying to find the word, because there are no clear rules of how to use metaphors, except some people often agrees that metaphors used in a certain way is bad or improper or bad style.

Comment: An assault on good taste, it’ll get ya 3-5 in the big house.

Answer (score 1):

I've typically heard the word "malaproper" or "malapropism" are the correct word to use for a misuse of a metaphor or other type of sentence (simile, allegory), though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When a second metaphor is used very soon after another, care should be taken to ensure that there isn't a ludicrous clash:

- *If there is a spark of pity in your hearts, water it and let it grow.*

Such mangling of the language is termed **mixed metaphor** (see [Nordquist's article at ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-mixed-metaphor-1691395) for other comical examples).

The term is sometimes extended to cover poor choice of metaphor:

- *John's a tiger; don't mess with him!*
- ??*That lion's a tiger; don't mess with it!*

Overblown, pretentious metaphors are sometimes used:

- *This small car is a Pegasus soaring above the competition.*